# Range SeekBar Android

Tags: android

Boa tarde,
Preciso fazer o SeekBar como o dessa imagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso fazer isso? O SeekBar nativo e mais simples sem essa opcão dupla.

Comment: https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.